# Unable to compile vapoursynth: failed to link zimg

Tags: compiling, configure, linker

I'm trying to compile vapoursynth and have run into a linker issue which I don't understand how to solve. Here is what I have so far:

I have compiled zimg from github

```
github: buaazp/zimg
```

and have a binary. I pulled vapoursynth from here

```
github: vapoursynth/vapoursynth
```

and I followed the [instructions](http://www.vapoursynth.com/doc/installation.html#linux-and-os-x-compilation-instructions).

When I try to run `./configure`:

> configure: error: Package requirements (zimg) were not met:
>   No package 'zimg' found
>   Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>   Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ZIMG_CFLAGS
>   and ZIMG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
>   See the pkg-config man page for more details.

I tried to fix it with:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/test/zimg/bin/zimg
```

But `./configure` still didn't work and had the same error. Then I tried:

```
export ZIMG_CFLAGS=/home/test/zimg/src/
export ZIMG_LIBS=/home/test/zimg/build
```

And the check for zimg passed, but it fails to link it. The error is this:

> checking for ZIMG... yes
>   configure: error: failed to link zimg.

What should I try next?

Comment: Just a note about `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`: It should point to where `pkg-config` may find the `pkgconfig` directories. You find these directories under `lib`, for example in `<prefix>/lib` where `<prefix>` is the installation prefix for `zimg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I used the wrong zimg. The correct zimg is `sekrit-twc/zimg`.